# Running Pig with a JAR as a UDF returns ERROR 101

Tags: apache-pig, oozie

I'm new to Pig and Oozie, so this might be a beginners question, yet I've searched everywhere for an answer, without luck...
I'm trying to run an UDF on Pig, the UDF is a JAR with eval method overloaded (taken from http://wiki.apache.org/pig/UDFManual):

```
package myudfs;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.pig.EvalFunc;
import org.apache.pig.data.Tuple;
import org.apache.pig.impl.util.WrappedIOException;

public class UPPER extends EvalFunc<String>
{
    public String exec(Tuple input) throws IOException {
        if (input == null || input.size() == 0)
            return null;
        try {
            String str = (String)input.get(0);
            return str.toUpperCase();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

while the Pig script is:

```
REGISTER myudfs.jar;
Raw = LOAD '/user/piguser/input' AS (name: chararray, age: int, gpa: int);
x = FOREACH Raw GENERATE myudfs.UPPER(name);
RMF 'output';
STORE x INTO 'output';
```

when running this on local (pig -f script.pig.txt) I'm receiving the desired results, yet when running this on Oozie (`oozie job -oozie http://localhost:11000/oozie -config job.properties -run`) I'm receiving the following error:
 *ERROR 101: Local file 'myudfs.jar' does not exist.*

What would you suggest me to do?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: The Pig version is 0.9.3

Comment: Where is the jar located? Have you tried using the full path of the jar?

Comment: Yes I did, both the full path (*/full/path/to/file*), the relative path (*./file*) and even just the file name (*file*).

Answer (score 1):

See Case 4, here:  [Pig Cookbook](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/OOZIE/Pig+Cookbook)

Summarizing, there are three ways you can choose:

1. Put your jar file in a folder named "lib" beneath the Workflow and Pig file
2. Use the `<archive>` tag in your pig-action to specify the location of the file.
3. Use the `<file>` tag in your pig-action to specify the location of the file.

Personally I use the `<file>` tag, but I've experimented with using a lib folder as well, and it works fine.

EDIT: You may need to include a symlink in your file tag.  e.g. `<file>myudfs.jar#myudfs.jar</file>`.

Comment: If you use the "lib" folder technique then you need to remove the `register` statement from the pig script because jars in the lib directory are automatically added to the classpath by Oozie server